# Остановка System.Threading.Timer

Tags: c#, консоль, таймер

Возможно очень глупый вопрос от новичка.
Буду рад прочесть все что скинете.
Задался такой задачей.
Как остановить таймер при определенном условии из другого метода? 
Как сделать это лучше?

```
static void Main () 
{
    Timer timer1 = new Timer(MyMethod, num, 0, 1000);
}
public static void MyMethod(object obj)
{
    Do something
}
```

Условно в методе что-то выполниться, если метод что-то находит, то dispose() таймер.

Comment: Почему вы хотите использовать таймер из пространства System.Threading.Timer, а не из System.Timers.Timer?

Comment: Да просто примеров с ним вроде как было больше, скажите по опыту какой лучше. И как лучше это сделать.

Comment: Виды таймеров - [раз](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/threads/timers.html), [два](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/threading/timers)

Comment: Чтобы использовать таймер в методе, сделайте его полем класса или передавайте в метод как параметр, или сделайте функцию локальной или делегатом.

Comment: Полем пробовал до этого объявлял так ```private static Timer _timer;
и вызывал методе .dispose() и вышла ошибка: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынести как поле (самый простой вариант)

```
static Timer timer1;

static void Main () 
{
    timer1 = new Timer(MyMethod, num, 0, 1000);
}
public static void MyMethod(object obj)
{
    timer1.Change(....);
}
```

Сделать функцию локальной

```
static void Main () 
{
    Timer timer1 = new Timer(MyMethod, num, 0, 1000);

    void MyMethod(object obj)
    {
        timer1.Change(....);
    }
}
```

Передать как параметр

```
static void Main () 
{
    Timer timer1 = null;
     timer1 = new Timer(MyMethod, new Func<Timer>(()=>timer1), 0, 1000);        
}

public static void MyMethod(object obj)
{
    var timer = ((Func<Timer>) obj)();
    timer.Change(....);
}
```

Comment: мда...даже не знаю сказать, ошибка была в том, что перед  `timer1 = new Timer`.....Я видимо случайно ставил `Timer timer1 = new Timer`. Позор.
Спасибо!

Comment: @DaniilKuzmin если ответ вам дейсвительно помог решить вашу проблему, то слева у ответа нажмите галочку.